# Internet goes on and off in windows 7, glitch?

Tags: windows-7, internet, ethernet

Recently I had installed a new PCI ethernet adapter since the motherboard ethernet was broken. Everything worked fine and I did not install any drivers for it since Windows 7 normally detects it.

After working for it for over approx. a week, the internet randomly starts going on and off in Windows 7. Well actually, it tries to connect and eventually after 15mins it will, but then will turn off again some time later.

I do not think that it has anything to do with my ISP and the router since other computers and wireless connections just work fine on this router. I have no idea what the problem is, but I was thinking that it might be a sort of bug that is easily fixable in windows 7.

P.S. I have made small video to highlight the problem, here it is:  http://aasingercom.ipage.com/files/capture-1.avi (164KB)

Comment: Connection issue with the cable/socket? It sounds like temperature might play a role as well.

Comment: Maybe a bad pci ethernet adapter? Just because it is new does not guarantee it will not become defective at some point in time.

Comment: Hmm, could be. Do you think swapping it to another pci slot will make a difference? Because I have an other of these adapters in my other computer and everything works fine